# How obtain a new property from Eloquent collection subitem

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Model Article and another Category which are in relation

```
class Article extends Model
{
    // ...
    
    public function categorie()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'article_category', 'article_codice_base', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Now if I execute

```
Article::find('100aa')->load('categorie')
```

it returns this collection

```
App\Models\Article {#4722
     codice_base: "100aa",
     created_at: "2022-12-09 14:29:38",
     updated_at: "2022-12-09 17:55:15",
     name: "TOP100",
     description: "lorem ipsum sic dolor.....",
     published: 1,
     thumbnail: "",
     prezzo_base: "93.50",
     costo_grossista: "68.50",
     resource_id: "97f0992e-0088-4476-b65d-6d6f708ac81c",
     sconto_id: null,
     categorie: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4713
       all: [
         App\Models\Category {#4732
           id: 13,
           created_at: "2022-12-07 11:37:17",
           updated_at: "2022-12-07 14:45:44",
           name: "CATEG01",
           sequenza_visualizzazione: 15,
           published: 0,
           thumbnail: "",
           resource_id: "97ec5591-e302-4c02-8a8a-6103aa179e87",
           catalogue_name: "CATALOGUE-A",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#4730
             article_codice_base: "100aa",
             category_id: 13,
           },
         },
         App\Models\Category {#4733
           id: 14,
           created_at: "2022-12-07 16:03:14",
           updated_at: "2022-12-07 16:03:14",
           name: "CATEG02",
           sequenza_visualizzazione: 14,
           published: 1,
           thumbnail: "",
           resource_id: "97ecb4ae-7380-4281-a2e0-53aaeb14d317",
           catalogue_name: "CATALOGUE-B",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#4729
             article_codice_base: "100aa",
             category_id: 14,
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
```

Is there a way to get only the categorie.name property and implode them in another direct property of the article class? I defintively need to obtain something like this

```
 App\Models\Article {#4722
     codice_base: "100aa",
     created_at: "2022-12-09 14:29:38",
     updated_at: "2022-12-09 17:55:15",
     name: "TOP100",
     description: "lorem ipsum sic dolor.....",
     published: 1,
     thumbnail: "",
     prezzo_base: "93.50",
     costo_grossista: "68.50",
     resource_id: "97f0992e-0088-4476-b65d-6d6f708ac81c",
     sconto_id: null,
     categorie_imploded: "CATEG01, CATEG02"
   }
```

with or without the original "categorie" property is not an issue.

I was able to implode the data in a string writing a new method in the Article Model

```
public function categorie_imploded()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'article_category', 'article_codice_base', 'category_id')->pluck('name')->implode(', ');
}
```

that return me this element "CATEG01, CATEG02" but I didn't find a way to obtain the final collection with this new property.

Comment: What do you mean "I didn't find a way to obtain the final collection", what is "the final collection"? Could you give an example with that "collection" as a result?

Comment: You can use `->with('category:name')`, and then do `$article->categorie->pluck('name')`, you will get an array of category names and you can use implode on it if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Having this `$article`

```php
$article = Article::find('100aa')->load('categorie');
```

Which is the same as

```php
$article = Article::with('categorie')->find('100aa');
```

You can turn `$article->categorie` into a string. `$article->categorie` is an Eloquent Collection. You can use Collection methods to transform it into a single value.

```php
# Using map and join
$article->categorie = $article->categorie
    ->map(function ($categorie) {
        return $categorie->name;
    })
    // or map(fn ($categorie) => $categorie->name) if using PHP > 7.4
    ->join(', ');
```

```php
# Using map and join with High Order Messages:
$article->categorie = $article->categorie->map->name->join(', ');
```

```php
# Using pluck and join:
$article->categorie = $article->categorie->pluck('name')->join(', ');
```

---

If you want another property, you could define an accessor in the Article model.

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    public function getCategorieImplodedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->categorie->... // paste here any of the implementations above
    }
}
```

```php
Article::with('categorie')->find('100aa')->categorie_imploded
```

Make sure to eager load the categorie relationship to avoid N+1 queries.

Comment: Hi @IGP, thank you for your reply. All of your solutions convert the "categorie" content to a string, but I would need to get the string as "property" of the $article object because I need to pass the entre object as a property of a Vue js view component.

Really I have to work on the entire collection of articles, so  I tried also
$articles = Article::all();
$articles->each(function($article, $key) {echo $article->categorie = $article->categorie->map->name->join(', ');;});
but I have the same problem; the collection does not contain the new "string" instead of categories array of objects

Comment: The getCategorieImplodedAttribute() create a new property wich can be accessed:
$article ->categorie_imploded